# change right hand job listing layout

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Can we change the layout of this to bring in a little structure and meaning:

[image]

The links on the bottom of the listing are not in any particular useful order.  Maybe organize it by type.  In this case we have two things we are dealing with:

1. sharing the job
2. taking action on the job

The sharing could group the mail, twitter, and facebook icons.  The actions could group favoriting ore flagging a problem...Just a thought, maybe something like this:

[image]

The more x jobs... could be moved below all of it, if it makes more sense.  Notice the share starts with email as that is the most common.  I don't know anyone who wants to share a job via facebook, but I can see people asking for that feature.  The most common thing is that most if not everyone has an email, besides you wouldn't have a facebook / twitter account without that email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback Jon. We've grouped all the sharing actions together but haven't gone as far as changing the design of the sidebar completely. We'll likely be covering that in the coming weeks.

Comment: I'll accept this but it still looks like garbage :-o.